# How to use return values from two functions to make an if statement and break process

Tags: python-3.x, arduino, python-multithreading

I'm trying to run a program where if my values are within the threshold my States 1 and 2 become positive. I want it to be such that when both states are positive the program breaks. However, I'm unable to use the values from my States.

How should I proceed with this problem?

```
import concurrent.futures


def Vibration1(a,b,c,d):
    State1 = False
    if a < Thumb_Pitch < b or c < Roll_Max_Thumb < d :
        State1 = True

    else:
        State1 = False
        print('Done1')
    return State1

def Vibration2(w,x,y,z):
    State2 = False
    if w < Index_Pitch < x or y < Index_Roll < z :
        State2 = True
    else:
        State2 = False
        print('Done2')
    return State2

def feedback():
    Success = False
    if State1 and State2  == True:
        Success = True
        x = time.sleep(5)
    else:
        Success = False
        print("Keep Trying")


    return print('Success',Success)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f1 = executor.submit(Vibration1,-3000.0,3000.0,-3000.0,3000.0)
        f2 = executor.submit(Vibration2,-3000.0,3000.0,-3000.0,3000.00)
        f3 = executor.submit(feedback)

        print(f1.result())
        print(f2.result())
        print(f3.result())
```

Comment: why `return print('Success', Success)` thats not great practice, maybe stick to either option.

Comment: `State1` and `State2` are local variables in the functions, you can't access them in `feedback()`

Comment: Also, `if State1 and State2 == True:` should be `if State1 and State2`.

Comment: You can't run `feedback` concurrently with the vibration functions. It won't wait for them to finish and set their state variables.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Your code is breaking style conventions, and as a result it's more difficult to read.

Comment: Hey Bamar, How should my code by structured? The feed the vibration functions are reading is in real-time, so at every iteration, it must check if all the vibration functions have been met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you can not reference the variables from the functions `Vibration1` and `Vibration2`.

### There are two ways to do this.

### 1) You can assign the values to global variables:

```
import concurrent.futures

State1 = None
State2 = None

def Vibration1(a,b,c,d):
    global State1
    State1 = False
    if a < Thumb_Pitch < b or c < Roll_Max_Thumb < d :
        State1 = True

    else:
        State1 = False
        print('Done1')
    return State1

def Vibration2(w,x,y,z):
    global State2
    State2 = False
    if w < Index_Pitch < x or y < Index_Roll < z :
        State2 = True
    else:
        State2 = False
        print('Done2')
    return State2

def feedback(a,b,c,d,w,x,y,z):
    global State1
    global State2
    Success = False
    if State1 and State2:
        Success = True
        x = time.sleep(5)
        State1 = False
        State2 = False
    else:
        Success = False
        print("Keep Trying")


    return print('Success',Success)
```

If you do this, you will have to call the `Vibration1` and `Vibration2` functions externally in order to assign the values of the variables.

### 2) When you reference the values State1 and State2 you call the vibration function:

```
def feedback(a,b,c,d,w,x,y,z):
    Success = False
    if Vibration1(a,b,c,d) and Vibration2(w,x,y,z):
        Success = True
        x = time.sleep(5)
    else:
        Success = False
        print("Keep Trying")


    return print('Success',Success)
```

This way you don't have to call the functions externally, they will be called automatically.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: get rid of `== True`

Comment: But he's trying to run the code in parallel with `concurrent.futures`. This will run them sequentially.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks, changed it to use global variables.

Comment: Of course, it still doesn't really make sense because `feedback` isn't waiting for the vibration functions to finish.

Comment: There are two options, you call the functions within the function, or you use global variables and call the functions externally. I don't think he specified needing these functions to be run in parallel.

Comment: Can anyone advise on how to run these parallel? At this point, I've used the code above which has improved how the whole program runs but right now the main problem is, that I have 5 functions for Vibrations1,2,3,4,5. When any of them is False, I send a serial.write to an Arduino with a command for the specific motor (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5) to vibrate. However, right now, the motor vibration is very random and mostly only the 1st of 2nd motor vibrate.

Answer (score 1):

global variables are not really good practice, but the simplistic solution would be to declare `State1` and `State2` as globals.

you do this by adding the lines

```
    global State1
    global State2
```

at the beginning of each function that wants to modify `State1` or `State2`